# Arduino communication with computer error

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, serial-communication, avrdude

My Arduino Uno R3 was functioning as normal when the Uno stopped communicating with the computer. The device manager could see the uno, and it wasn't hardware or code as I tried uploading the Blink example code to no avail. I am pretty sure all drivers are up to date and I selected the right port and Arduino.

This is the error message it gave me:

Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

````
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.


avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
the selected serial port avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
 does not exist or your board is not connected
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The device does not recognize the command.


avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The device does not recognize the command.


avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The device does not recognize the command.


avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The device does not recognize the command.


avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: sorry no info avail
avrdude: ser_recv(): read error: The device does not recognize the command.


avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x20
avrdude: ser_drain(): read error: The device does not recognize the command.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.```
````

Comment: it could be a damaged USB cable

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming related question, which makes it off-topic here. You may be able to get help at [arduino.se] instead, but I'd suggest you review their help center pages before posting to make sure the site is appropriate for your question. You can find this site's guidelines in the [help].